# Keyboard not functioning during reboot, cannot access boot menu

Tags: keyboard

Im running Ubuntu 13.04.  I want to access my boot menu consists of just holding down the esc key during reboot.  Problem is.....my keyboard doesnt activate until ubuntu is almost booted completely.  In other words I can push any key I want and my computer doesnt know it because the keyboard isnt on.  I put in a boot disk and all it does produce a another keyboard request..."Hit any key to run from CD".

tulsahawk823@aol.com

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem which I've documented here: [Can't access keyboard in boot menu after update to Ubuntu 14.0.1, laptop keyboard, trackpad, network not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525783/cant-access-keyboard-in-boot-menu-after-update-to-ubuntu-14-0-1-laptop-keyboar) As you can read from the title I had some other troubles as well. The get to the GRUB menu I read up on grub and [deactivated the ACPI system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options) thusly:

edited grub configuration:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and changed this variable:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quit splash acpi=ht"
```

Comment: This will only change the kernel line, but Grub fails to recognise the keyboard before the kernel is booted.